# Can I move my save data/will it be automatically moved from Sleeping Dogs to SD: Definitive Edition?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I'm thinking about buying [Sleeping Dogs: Definitive Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/307690/) but I'm in a good position in the original Sleeping Dogs and I have it installed. I don't want to lose my save data, if I buy Sleeping Dogs: Definitive Edition, will my save data be automatically moved/can I move it?

Comment: You can backup/save the games from 1 to another sleeping dog game on a diffrent pc. SD:DE is a diffrent game and the save files are not cross compatibale, is what alot of people are saying in the steam forums, who have tryed to migrate saves from the original

Comment: @rwank I bought it specifically to answer the question. Downloading ATM, will confirm/deny if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't not move save datas between the games.

Confirmation from the developer can be found [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/307690/discussions/0/620695877346583674/#c620695877360977253).